# Custom styles and scripts for specific admin screen

Tags: admin

Which is the best way to load different scripts and/or styles for different admin pages?

For example:

1. edit.php (a style, a script)
2. edit.php?post_type=page (another style, another script)
3. edit.php?post_type=_my_custom_post (none script, yet another style)

end so on...

the get_current_screen() function should help the process, but I'm not sure which actions to use and how.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated,
thank you very much.

Comment: Did you search for the solutions in here, I can think of possible question been answered here before

Comment: Take a look at the [WCM Current Admin Info](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/current-admin-info) plugin. I wrote that for exactly that purpose: Easier and faster development while targeting exactly what you need.